# Android layout designer in VS dont work

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

Using Xamarin I can't solve the error when open even the default layout.

**"
Something weng wrong
The installed Android SDK it to old. Version 25.1.3 or newer is 
required. Please update to the latest version.
"**

As seen in the image below I already installed the latest tools.
[image: SDK Manager]

Using Java 1.8. Did I miss something?
Thank you very much.

[image: Additional config details]

Comment: Just as a first small sanity-check, you can look to see whether the Android SDK path (displayed just off the top of the current screenshot in the question) does match the path shown under _Tools > Options > Xamarin > Android Settings > Android SDK Location_.

Comment: Thanks. But I did check that. Added screenshot. *phew, sanity-check passed*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Here a solution that worked for me:

1) delete the one package appearing in the screenshot of the Android SDK Manager in the url below. Nota bene: At this stage VS 2015 greyed out the Android SDK manager buttons, even after a restart.

2) download installer_r24.4.1-windows.exe for windows https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

3) launch the Android SDK Manager outside of VS and install the proposed 19 packages. This time I could go through the installation.

4) Launch VS 2015 and create Xamarin Android project. Launching Main.axml would launch the designer properly on an android project.

More details here
[How to resolve : unexpected error occured Initializing Android Designer" in VS 2015 with Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548053/how-to-resolve-unexpected-error-occured-initializing-android-designer-in-vs-2/39548507#39548507)